# Añadir datos a un Array de MongoDB - Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, angular7

tengo una aplicacion muy basica, sobre registro de clientes.

Tengo un modelo de clientes, en el mismo hay un array de "registros" vacio.

cliente.js - Model

```
var mongoose =  require('mongoose');
var Schema =    mongoose.Schema;


var clienteSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: { type: String,required: [true,'El nombre es necesario']},
    actividad: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: true},
    usuario: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Usuario'},
    registros: [],
},{
    timestamps: true,
}
);

module.exports =    mongoose.model('Cliente', clienteSchema);
```

La idea es que al crear un cliente se pueda añadir datos al arreglo vacio

Algo tal que asi deberia quedar o es la idea al traer todos los clientes de la bd.

```
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cdc5ddc349a9a461cea9202"),
            "created" : ISODate("2019-05-15T18:43:24.372Z"),
            "actividad" : true,
            "registros" : [{
                          "mes":"Mayo",
                          "detalle": [
                                  {
                                   "tipo": "extra"
                                   "cantidad":"5"
                                  },
{
                          "mes":"Junio",
                          "detalle": [
                                  {
                                   "tipo": "normal"
                                   "cantidad":"2"
                                  }
                                     ]
    }],
            "nombre" : "Test",
            "usuario" : ObjectId("5cd98354035bae40fc0586af"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-05-15T18:43:40.752Z"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-05-15T18:43:40.752Z"),
            "__v" : 0
        }
```

Estos datos los deberia ingresar el usuario que esta asignado a ese cliente.
Como puedo hacer la consulta para postear la informacion dentro del array registro?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: porque no creas una conexion de registros y asocias al cliente? como lo hicistes con el usuario

Comment: Me parecio que asi era mejor, pero en ese caso deberia treaer registros que tengan la misma id que el cliente. El cual no sabria bien como hacerlo. Entiendo que es algo mas complejo ya que deberia de hacer  dos consultas para traer el cliente y los registros que tienen ese cliente asignado, verdad?

Comment: No es necesario hacer 2 consultas, la solución que te plantea @JackNavaRow es la mejor opción. Y cuando consultas un cliente llenas los datos del array de registros con `populate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
updateRegistroCliente(clienteID, registroObject) {
        const updatedObject= ClienteModel.findByIdAndUpdate(clienteID,
            { $push: { 'registros': registroObject} },
            { strict: false },
            (err, managerparent) => {
                if (err) {
                    return err.message;
                }
            }
        );
        return updatedObject;
}
```

Deberás hacer una petición put y pasarle el id de ese cliente creado por Mongo al insertarlo en la base de datos. Si no lo haces por el id cambiaría un poco pero la filosofía sería la misma. Este metodo añadiría el objeto de registros dentro del array en la base de datos. Donde "registroObject" será el objeto a introducir.